# Find duplicates in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Could somebody tell me what the following line in the code that was provided by my tutor is supposed to be doing?

```
if (data.contains(entry))
```

Full method:

```
public String add(Entry entry) {
    if (entry == null)
      return "Error: null entry";
    if (data.contains(entry))
      return "Error: this entry already in the book";

    boolean done = data.add(entry);    
    if (done)
      return " entry added";
    else
      return "entry could not be added";
  }
```

I thought it was checking for an existing entry with the same details within the ArrayList but when I add a duplicate entry it doesnt go into the `if` statement so figured I assumed wrong? I searched around on the Internet and it says it's for this purpose so why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: have you tried to compare the objects outside the if, to see if the are the same (using the equals method) ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: @rockskull havent done anything with the methods within this class as we are unable to modify it in anyway. We have extend the classes given to create an address book. He must be wanting us to use this contains somehow otherwise why would they put it in there?

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that returning a string status from a Java method is not normal. Instead, if you have no meaningful return value make it a `void` method. If something goes wrong, throw an exception.

Comment: @DuncanJones I only wish I could. We have to use exceptions within the program and I was hoping to throw them from this class however because we wernt allowed to modify it I asked him where exactly I was going to include exceptions and their expecting us to put them in for validation on user input on the form which I think is wrong.

Comment: @ToniHopkins Your teacher sounds like a real winner :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that `contains()` performs an equality check with `equals()`. So unless your object overrides that method, it will not consider objects to be equal unless they are the same object reference.

Of course, don't override `equals()` without overriding `hashCode()` too.

Finally, if you don't want duplicate objects consider using a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Comment: To clarify, if you don't overload `equals` no two instances of non-primitive objects will ever be considered to be equal (because it uses the memory address of the instance) and therefore `contains` will always return false.

Comment: @DuncanJones I cant modify this method in anyway (any of the class for that matter) so does that mean it serves no purpose if its not actually checking for duplicate entries? Appologies im new to java

Comment: @ToniHopkins To be clear, are you able to edit the `Entry` class?

Comment: @DuncanJones No im not allowed to touch this class in anyway. Iv been told on many occasions that the code within this class is shocking. I think thats what is stressing me out most as people keep suggesting best ways to do things but im not allowed to implement them.

Comment: @ToniHopkins If you can't change the code, why post a question? :-)

Comment: @DuncanJones I wasnt sure of its purpose as I thought it was supposed to be checking for duplicate entries but wasnt working =(

Answer (score 1):

Check your equals() and hashcode()

Answer (score 0):

List's `contains()` method you will see that it uses the `equals`() method to evaluate if two objects are the same.

internal logic [as per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e));
```

So you have to `ovveride` the `equals` method to `compare` them